# Find only between marks

Tags: search, mark

Suppose that I have marks `'a` and `'b`, and I want to search for all occurrences of `foo` between them.

The `ex` command

```
:'a,'bs/foo/bar
```

will *replace* only between `'a` and `'b`.  Is there any command like

```
:'a,'b/foo
```

that will *find* `foo` only between those two marks?  (That exact syntax does *something*, but I can't figure out what.  It doesn't seem to be what I want.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\%>'m` and `\%<'m` to match after and before a given mark, `m`.

```
/\%>'afoo\%<'b
```

For more helps see:

```
:h /\%'m
```

Comment: Thank you!  And then some more characters.

Comment: Do you know what my imaginary syntax `:'a,'b/foo` is doing?  The effect that I observe is that I jump to some other part of the document, way outside the mark-delimited region, but I can't figure out why I'm going there.

Comment: `'a,'b` is a range. So you can actually type this out as it to see what it does: `:'a,'b`. It will move to the `'b` position as that is the end of the range. You then execute a command, e.g. `/`. So it searches for `foo` after line `'b`. For more help see `:h :range`

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that I was inadvertently concatenating two commands.  Thanks!

Comment: @LSpice, see if you can learn how this one works: `:'a,'b/hello/d` "delete from the line of mark a through the first line containing the word hello after the line of mark b"

Comment: @Mass, thanks!  So does that mean that it's not just `'a,'b` that's the range, but `'a,'b/hello/`, where the start of the range is `'a` and the end is `'b/hello/`?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW: 
:'a,'bs/foo//**n**
substitute foo with nothing and choose 'no' when asked for the replacement.
afterwards just hit the next (n) to get to the next occurrence.

Comment: Thanks!  It's not the spirit of what I wanted, but it's an interesting approach.

Comment: I also use it to count number of occurrences in the buffer: %s/foo//n

Comment: [Re](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15587/find-only-between-marks#comment53201_22080), how do you extract the count (or do you just tally it manually)?

Comment: e.g. When you have 24 `foo`  in your buffer, the command `%s/foo//n` outputs the answer: 24 matches on 24 lines.

Comment: I was overthinking [that](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15587/find-only-between-marks/22080#comment68857_22080)!  Thanks!